# Disconnect menu option not showing up in subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm trying to disconnect a project from a subversion repository but the disconnect option is not showing up in the submenu. There are conflicts (from when I tried to do an earlier synchronization) but I don't care about resolving the conflicts. I just want to remove the local copy and re-update from the repository. Here's a screen shot of the folder in question (site) in eclipse:

[image: Screen shot of eclipse]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to disconnect at a sub-folder level rather than at the project level where the inital checkout occurred. I ended up breaking up the project in subversion into several projects, cleaning everything off of the file system, and doing a check-out using subclipse. Now everything is synched-up as expected.